# How To Create A Bootable USB Installer for Windows, Linux and OSX?

Tags: macos, windows, usb, install, bootable-disk

How can I use my 120GB USB Drive as an ultimate IT tool?

I want to have the following ISOs partitioned off and accessible through a bootloader (any):

Windows 5,6,7,8,10
OSX 10.6,7,8,9,10
GParted (Live)
Kali (Live)
Hiren

I have all of the ISOs, but I have had no success so far.  I don't think tools are the answers as I tried Xboot and another one.

Anyone had any luck with this or have any ideas?

Comment: That's a pretty tall order. Getting all your OSes to coexist and be bootable without some sort of contention is going to take some work. Obviously you'll need MBR as the underlying partition table for the Windows partitions to be recognised. Fortunately the OS X installers *are* bootable when using MBR in spite of Apple's insistence on GUID for Apple boot drives, and they will happily sit on their own partitions and be selectable at startup. I suspect the Windows partitions are going to cause headaches, unsure about Linux as I've only ever had one distro per USB stick. Good luck!

Comment: My best bet is to install a Windows VM (VirtualBox, Parallels, etc.) and use [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create the bootable USB.